# sql error (1241): operand should contain 1 column(s) - order by dates

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1241

I'm trying to find the last deployment associated to a serial number, and without getting the latest date, I get multiple lines for a particular serial number.  I'm getting the error 1241 when I enter the following:

```
select deployment, device_serial_number from action_archive 
where (.....)
group by device_serial_number
order by 'date'
```

Comment: Add the complete error message

Comment: Why are you using a `group by` without any aggregation at all?

Comment: Why is date enclosed by single quotes? Single quotes mean string and order by would require a column or expression.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a subquery.  It looks like this:

```
select aa.*
rom action_archive aa
where (.....) and
      `date` = (select max(aa2.date)
                from action_archive aa2
                where . . . and
                      aa2.device_serial_number = aa.device_serial_number
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the quotations in "'date'". Try this:

```
SELECT deployment,
   device_serial_number 
FROM action_archive 
WHERE (.....) 
GROUP BY device_serial_number 
ORDER BY date
```

Also, I think you might have problems with the GROUP BY, maybe you should  add "deployment" there too.